# ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined in openstreetmap

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers

Hello I'm trying to implement a marker to the `openstreetstreetmap` and it is showing the error in firebug as `ReferenceError: OpenLayers is not defined`. Here is the code which I have implemented :

```
<script>
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
        projection: "EPSG:900913",
        displayProjection: "EPSG:4326"
    });
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
    var markers = new
    OpenLayers.Layer.Text("text", {location: "<?php echo $root_url; ?>"+"/marker_a.png", projection: map.displayProjection});
    map.addLayer(markers);
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
</script>
<body>
    <iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=77.4471,12.8607,77.7664,13.0728&layer=mapnik" style="border: 1px solid black"></iframe>
    <br />
    <small>
        <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/?lat=12.96675&lon=77.60675&zoom=14&layers=M">View Larger Map</a>
    </small>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi guys I got the solution for this one the code which I used is here

Comment: 'image = "<?php echo $root_url; ?>" + "/marker_a.png";
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);                        
var icon1 = new OpenLayers.Icon(image, size, offset);
var lonLat1 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(res[2],res[1]).transform(
  new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), // transform from WGS 1984
map.getProjectionObject() // to Spherical Mercator Projection
); 
                        var marker1 = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat1, icon1);
marker1.icon.size = size;
marker1.icon.offset = offset;
markers.addMarker(marker1, icon1);

Comment: If you have managed to solve your question, please post your solution as an answer (this is actively encouraged!) :)

Comment: ok.. This is the first time I asked question in stackoverflow, So replied in comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script>
image = "<?php echo $root_url; ?>" + "/marker_a.png";
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h);
var icon1 = new OpenLayers.Icon(image, size, offset);
var lonLat1 = new OpenLayers.LonLat(res[2],res[1]).transform( new `OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), 
map.getProjectionObject());
var marker1 = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat1, icon1); 
marker1.icon.size = size; 
marker1.icon.offset = offset; 
markers.addMarker(marker1, icon1); 
</script>
```